# Web application memory usage growing up to 800 MB during the day

Tags: .net, iis, memory

My team deployed a new software version in .NET on our server with IIS.

We noticed sometime during the day, the memory usage of that application grows up to 800 MB.

In that case, the application doesn't answer. I don't have any idea about how to solve it and reproduct in dev env. We didn't do any specific modifications except the numbers of users really increase.

My assumption is I need to add some monitor in the .net Code to permit to identify the issue(s). Currently, I need to connect on the server and restart IIS until the next day. Do you have any advise to identify the point? A tool permitting to check where this bad thing happends?

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is a web application.

I would at first check if a specific mechanism is causing the problem. Do you use Sessions/Cache/etc.

Even if you might think: No, your controls might use them automaticly. Controls with a lot of display data (e.g. DataGrids) can be an issue)

You should keep an eye on those (and measure them) if they increase up to nearly the 800MB so you can investigate further

Comment: Yes it's a web application in ASP.NET MVC4 without control as Telerik or external provider. I begin to investigate and I find a tool System Center Manager. I test it.